# Can I test run items in Single Player for Team Fortress 2?

Tags: team-fortress-2

While playing TF2 I decided to go to the Mann co. store to look around and browse. Well I quickly found out I can use items for free for a week.

I decided to test the Heavy's *Natasha* Minigun . I went on a Payload Race server and tried out the gun. I know I am able to use this new toy on multiplayer servers, but can I use them on the offline training mode as well?

Comment: Are you referring to the tutorial or creating an offline server?

Comment: When you click on training there should be a training section and offline training featuring payload, control points and king of the hill

Comment: I'm not sure about training, that may be vanilla class layouts only. But with offline servers, you can definitely add bots and use any class configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a basic map were you can spawn any class with any weapon and just want a idle bot under your command you will need to do this

- Go to create server (plus sign next to servers)
- Start up server "itemtest"
- You start in spawn but an inaccessible room is near by for testing
- Enter command in console "sv_cheats 1"
- Then enter command in console "noclip"
- You will now be able to fly anywhere, like the now accessible room
- Once you get there just enter "noclip" back into the console to go back to normal
- Enter "itemtest" into console

From there you can add any class you want with anyone set of items and choose how you want to bot to act (e.g. stand while looking around and shooting repeatedly

Below is where the test area is located on the map. If you activate "noclip" and fly up you will see it

[image: Test room area]

I hope that helps!

Comment: Bucky, am I able to give them hats?

Comment: No, not that I know of, Sorry!

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can.

The Training (offline) bot mode will use any loadouts you have setup beforehand.  Even-though the mode itself is offline (as in, your PC is the server) the game itself is still online to keep your items and loadouts sync with Valve's servers.

If there's ever a point where you do get disconnected from the internet while playing, all characters will be defaulted to their normal loadouts until you're reconnected.

Note: There are training maps you can go out and download/install as well. [Walkway](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Walkway) being one of the most popular ones for testing and practicing without having to deal with objectives.  They're particularly useful when new weapons are released and players want to test out numbers and scenarios.